# Are all humans related to one mother and one father?

Tags: dna, human-evolution

Are all humans related to one mother and one father ?
What is proof for that?
If that is case,that mean brother and sister reproduce, this is incest, so how population survived?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and what makes a good question and answer. Please note the requirement for showing us your research into this question as outlined in the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) part of the help section.